# How to select fields with specific value with jq

Tags: json, select, jq

I want to select parent value where the field result is with a specific value

Here is the json i have :

```
{
    "lde-poc-01": {
        "file_|-linux-debian-login-uidmin_|-/etc/login.defs_|-replace": {
            "name": "/etc/login.defs",
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "result": true,
            "comment": "No changes needed to be made",
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/login",
            "__run_num__": 0,
            "start_time": "14:40:20.708675",
            "duration": 17.447,
            "__id__": "linux-debian-login-uidmin"
        },
        "file_|-linux-debian-login-uidmax_|-/etc/login.defs_|-replace": {
            "name": "/etc/login.defs",
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "result": true,
            "comment": "No changes needed to be made",
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/login",
            "__run_num__": 1,
            "start_time": "14:40:20.726336",
            "duration": 10.614,
            "__id__": "linux-debian-login-uidmax"
        },
        "file_|-linux-debian-login-sysuidmax_|-/etc/login.defs_|-replace": {
            "name": "/etc/login.defs",
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "result": true,
            "comment": "No changes needed to be made",
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/login",
            "__run_num__": 2,
            "start_time": "14:40:20.737165",
            "duration": 10.515,
            "__id__": "linux-debian-login-sysuidmax"
        },
        "file_|-linux-debian-login-gidmin_|-/etc/login.defs_|-replace": {
            "name": "/etc/login.defs",
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "result": true,
            "comment": "No changes needed to be made",
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/login",
            "__run_num__": 3,
            "start_time": "14:40:20.747892",
            "duration": 10.201,
            "__id__": "linux-debian-login-gidmin"
        },
        "file_|-linux-ubuntu-docker_|-/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list_|-managed": {
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "comment": "File /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list is in the correct state",
            "name": "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list",
            "result": true,
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/apt",
            "__run_num__": 9,
            "start_time": "14:40:20.873513",
            "duration": 40.569,
            "__id__": "linux-ubuntu-docker"
        },
        "cmd_|-linux-ubuntu-unattended-updrade-service_|-systemctl daemon-reload_|-run": {
            "changes": {},
            "result": false,
            "duration": 0.008,
            "start_time": "14:40:21.159608",
            "comment": "State was not run because none of the onchanges reqs changed",
            "__state_ran__": false,
            "__run_num__": 20,
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/apt"
        },
        "file_|-linux-ubuntu-upgrade-script-telegraf_|-/etc/telegraf/check-update.sh_|-managed": {
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "comment": "File /etc/telegraf/check-update.sh is in the correct state",
            "name": "/etc/telegraf/check-update.sh",
            "result": true,
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/apt",
            "__run_num__": 21,
            "start_time": "14:40:21.159685",
            "duration": 42.313,
            "__id__": "linux-ubuntu-upgrade-script-telegraf"
        },
        "file_|-linux-ubuntu-upgrade-telegraf_|-/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/update.conf_|-managed": {
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "comment": "File /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/update.conf is in the correct state",
            "name": "/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/update.conf",
            "result": true,
            "__sls__": "dev/linux/ubuntu/apt",
            "__run_num__": 22,
            "start_time": "14:40:21.202254",
            "duration": 51.238,
            "__id__": "linux-ubuntu-upgrade-telegraf"
        },
        "file_|-mysoc-po-python-rm2_|-/var/tmp/mysoc-po_|-absent": {
            "name": "/var/tmp/mysoc-po",
            "changes": {},
            "pchanges": {},
            "result": false,
            "comment": "File /var/tmp/mysoc-po is not present",
            "__sls__": "dev/mysoc-po",
            "__run_num__": 236,
            "start_time": "14:40:38.161788",
            "duration": 0.305,
            "__id__": "mysoc-po-python-rm2"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the values of comment / id and the parent value like ("file_|-mysoc-po-python-rm2_|-/var/tmp/mysoc-po_|-absent") where the field result is false.

I tried to use the select function but with no success

Thanks for your help

Comment: Something like `.[] | to_entries | map({ name:.key, id:.value.__id__, comment:.value.comment})` I guess.

Comment: `.[] | map(select(.result == false)) | to_entries | map({ name:.key, id:.value.__id__, comment:.value.comment})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
.[]
| to_entries
| map(select(.value.result == false))
| map({ name:.key, id:.value.__id__, comment:.value.comment})
```

`map(select(criteria))` is used to discard the items of an array (or the fields of an item in this case) which do not satisfy a criteria.

`to_entries` is used to craft an array of key/values from an item's fields.

Comment: I think `.[] | to_entries | map(select(.value.result == false)) | map({ name:.key, id:.value.__id__, comment:.value.comment})` would be correct. Using `map` first loses the key data like `file_|-linux-debian..` and result gets name value as 0,1,..

Comment: I tried but it returns an empty array.
```
# jq '.[] | to_entries | map(select(.result == false)) | map ({name:.key, id:.value.__id__, comment:.value.comment})' test.json 
[]
```

Comment: ok i can get the correct value with that command : 
```jq .[] | to_entries | map(select(.value.result==false)) | map({name:.key, id:.value.__id__,comment:.value.comment,}) test.json```

Comment: Sorry you're right, I had a working solution at first but tried to improve it and didn't notice the names changed to incorrect values. I've updated my answer with the working solution you're using